# Mocha reporter does not seem to be taken into account when tests ran by chimp

Tags: npm, mocha.js, chimp.js

I have a very simple project that contains a *package.json* with this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "acceptance": "chimp --mocha --mochaReporter=mocha-junit-reporter  --chai --browser=chrome --path=src/spec/acceptance/**"
   },
  "devDependencies": {
  "chai": "^3.5.0",
  "chimp": "^0.47.1",
  "mocha": "^3.2.0",
  "mocha-junit-reporter": "^1.13.0",
  "uglify-js": "^2.7.5",
  "webdriverio": "^4.6.2"
},
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

To execute the tests, I'm running the following command:

```
npm run-script acceptance
```

Which makes chimp execute the tests with mocha (those are webdriverio tests, hence why I am using chimp)
The tests run as intended, however, there isn't any **test-results.xml** produced and the test results show up in the default "spec" format.

As suggested in the [documentation](https://chimp.readme.io/docs/reporting), I tried different alternatives such as creating a *chimp.js* file at the root of the project, that contains the following:

```
{
  mochaCommandLineOptions: ['--reporter mocha-junit-reporter'];
  mochaConfig: { reporter: 'mocha-junit-reporter' };
  mochaReporter: "mocha-junit-reporter";
}
```

But neither of these options seem to be taken into account.

So, anyone can tell me if I am doing something wrong?

ps: I have a separate unit testing script that works fine, and where custom reporting is taken into account, but for those, I'm simply using mocha without chimp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your chimp.js config file:

```
  mocha: true,
  chai: true,
  path: 'src/spec/acceptance/**',
  mochaConfig: {
    reporter: 'mocha-junit-reporter',
    reporterOptions: {
      mochaFile: './test-results.xml'
    }
  }
```